# React hooks - do not render the first time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom TextField component that can display when an error occurs, for instance, when a form is tried to be submitted with the textfield being empty. In that case, the field shows itself as 'red' with an appropiate error text.

The problem I'm facing is, that currently when I try to handle that logic from a Form Component, lets say a login, (I'm handling my required state with `useState(state, setState)` ) the TextField is 'red' on the first render, because its empty. This should only happen, when a user typed something and deleted it again, but not directly upon first render, since the TextField is empty anyway.

Previously I could have solved that with the `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle hook. Therefore, something like `useEffect(...)` should be used? I don't know how to go about it. Any ideas?

Comment: show us the code.

Comment: Why can't you use `componentDidUpdate()`?

Comment: I was looking for more of a conceptual hint. I would need to write a separate, independent example.

Comment: You should not mix react hooks with the old life cycle hooks, should you?

Comment: can you show us what you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useEffect hook to trigger the change from parent component, useEffect need a callback function and an array (called dependencies), when the values inside this array changed, useEffect perform the callback call.

Try this in your component

`const [value, setValue] = useState("");
 useEffect(() => setValue(initialValue), [initialValue]);`

`initialValue` is the value from your component (passing by props to child component, eg. your input field)

Answer (score 0):

This should be the conceptual solution I was looking for to my problem.

Here a small image showing the concept. For more, read the link down below.

[image]

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects